# Sending file to API with http client

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I'm working on sending a file to an api endpoint that is giving me the following curl example to post.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@submission.zip" api_url
```

This is the code I'm using - prior to this I'm getting a successful authentication response but a 500 response from this.

```
$file = fopen('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\api\\' . $fileName, 'r');

        return $this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'api_url', [
                'headers'=>[
                    'Authorization'=>$accessToken,
                    'Content-Type'=> 'multipart/form-data'
                ],
                'body'=>[
                    'file'=> $file
                ]
            ]
        );
```

I'm not sure what else I'm missing here. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get the 500 error? When accessing your script or as a response from the API? A 500 error is a server error and could mean anything. If it's your code that throws it, then I would recommend checking the web servers error log (if you execute it through a web server, that is).

Comment: Also, if you check the manual for [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), you can see that the return value isn't the file, it's a file pointer resource. I don't know what client you're using, but passing a file pointer resource seems odd. If you want to pass the file contents, use `file_get_contents('/path/to/file')` instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the input, I thought fopen seemed odd as well but I'm not a seasoned php dev so I was just going off of notes. The response is from the api server. I'm checking with the company to see if it could be that the api has some requirement that I'm missing. file_get_contents gives me the same exact error.

Comment: If you get 500 from the API for sending an improper request, I would argue that the API is broken. A proper API will return some info about what the issue is. A 500 error is just a generic "server error" that could be caused by anything. Btw, what http client are you using? Is it Symfonys? Checking the docs, it actually seems like it can take `fopen()` as argument. Strange.

Comment: If you [check the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#uploading-data) about Symfonys http client, it seems like you're missing some stuff. Check the third code block under "Uploading data" that starts with: `use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\DataPart;`. That looks like the answer below. If that doesn't work, I would hold on until the company that has the API comes back with an answer

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm almost positive the api is good, it's probably the way I'm sending the file or the file itself. I updated the code to reflect that part of the documentation and get the same error. I'll wait till I hear back from them then update this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to send the only file, then try to change your code to

```
'body' => fopen('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\api\\' . $fileName, 'r')
```

If you want to send the file with some fields, you can try something like this

```
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\DataPart;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\Multipart\FormDataPart;

$data = [
    'data' => 'some data',
    'file' => DataPart::fromPath('/path/to/file'),
];

$formData = new FormDataPart($data);
$headers = $formData->getPreparedHeaders()->toArray();
$headers['Authorization'] = $accessToken;
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
$client->request('POST', 'api_url', [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body' => $formData->bodyToIterable(),
]);
```

Comment: The file is all I need to send according to the documentation it looks like - I've tried it both the way I have it and your first suggestion but still getting a 500 response. I just wanted to make sure I was doing everything right. This is a .zip file that I'm trying to send, and I'm starting to suspect the test files I'm trying to send are being rejected by the server for some reason.

Comment: @BrianBarrick can you show your error? The second method works for me, try to create PHP file that will listen to some address and store a received file, for testing purposes.

Comment: Updated with the error details. Only removed ip/hostname/authentication data for privacy concerns.

Comment: @BrianBarrick Did you receive some response from the server?

Comment: The first call for authentication I get a 200 response and the token. The second call to the api with the token and the file gives me the 500 error.

Comment: How can I also send an integer field with the file?

Comment: It is important to understand that
`$headers = $formData->getPreparedHeaders()->toArray();`
return
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=_P5....`

respectively, this 
`$headers['Authorization'] = $accessToken;
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';`
needs to be replaced with
`$headers[] = "Authorization: Token {$accessToken}";`